# Way to use inner Html multiple times after user input?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Is there a way I can do something like this below?

```
function start(){
var action = document.getElementById("html_input_box").value;
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Would you like to begin?";
if (action == "start"){
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Welcome, you have begun."
}
}

start();
```

Is there a way to use innerHTML after user input more than once?

Comment: What do you mean by "use innerHTML more than once"?  What about this code isn't working as you expect?

Comment: If you mean that the second text overrides the first, it is enough tu put a '+=' instead of the '='. This way you'll append the text at the bottom

Comment: you want to append the HTML to textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I went about it..

HTML

```
<input id="html_input_box" onkeyup="start()" />
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

JS

```
function start(){
var action = document.getElementById("html_input_box").value;
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Would you like to begin?";
if (action == "start"){
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Welcome, you have begun."
  }
}
```

By adding  **onkeyup()** event and passing **start()** as a handler to the **input field**, the **textarea** field appends '**Welcome, you have begun**' with the append operator '**+=**' to the already existing text if and only if '**html_input_box**' has value of '**start**', any value other than '**start**' will resort to the original/former '**Would you like to begin?**'

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += action;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the innerHTML of textarea, you can use += append operator

```js
function start(){
var action = document.getElementById('action').value;
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = "Would you like to begin?";
if (action == "start"){
document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += " Welcome, you have begun."
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="action">
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
<button onclick="start()">Click</button>
```